# Download Generated File Using ASPX (VB.NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm generating an excel sheet, and would like the user to download it automatically (asks him if he accepts etc obviously), but I have tried the respond.writeFile() method, but all I got was a postback with funny characters, is there anyone kind enough to help me and explain to me how to do it please?

This is my code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("/uploads/monthly.xls")
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & path)
Dim contents As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(path)    
Response.Write(contents)
Response.End()
```

Comment: You're using `.DownloadString` to download a binary Excel file??

Comment: I'm new to ASPX I don't know, I'm trying to pop up the download thingy for the user when the file is completely generated.. :S

Comment: Have you tried [`Response.TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? i.e. `Response.TransmitFile(path)`.